# How do you connect to a Socks4 proxy using python's socket module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socks

I recently started using TCP with Python. I was trying to use Socks4 for a proxy, but it doesn't seem to be working. The code is below.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('148.77.34.200',54321)) # A random proxy I found
sock.send('\x04\x01\x00\x50\xbc\xb8\x15\x6c\x43\x68\x61\x64\x00'.encode())
#| VER | FUNC |    PORT   |        IP        |     Username      |
#| 0x04| 0x1  |  80 (0x50)|188.184.21.108    |Chad\0(not my name)|
print('Sent data')
a = sock.recv(8)
print(f'Received data {a}')
sock.close()
```

Sorry if the code is a little messy. Anyways, I was running the program but it either gave this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Aarav/OneDrive/Documents/testproxy.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = sock.recv(8)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

or it hung at sock.recv and returned b' '.

Does anyone happen to know how to fix this problem, or have documentation that would help?

**P.S.** I don't plan to use pysocks or request[socks], please don't give that as an answer.

**EDIT** The reason my program was failing because when UTF-8 converts non-ascii characters, it doesn't return it in the way I expected. I used `bytearray([0x04,0x01,0x00,0x50,0xbc,0xb8,0x15,0x6c,0x43,0x68,0x61,0x64,0x00])` instead of `'\x04\x01\x00\x50\xbc\xb8\x15\x6c\x43\x68\x61\x64\x00'.encode()` and it worked perfectly

Comment: It might be the way you encode the string. Try using a byte array:  `sock.send(bytearray([0x04,0x01,0x00,0x50,0xbc,0xb8,0x15,0x6c,0x43,0x68,0x61,0x64,0x00]))`

Comment: Your use of `encode()` is converting the string to bytes using UTF-8, which will not output what you are expecting for non-ASCII characters > 0x7F (ie, `\xbc` -> `0xC2 0xBC`, etc). So, you are actually sending a malformed SOCKS4 request (you can verify that with a packet sniffer). Use a byte array instead, or at least specify a charset to `encode()` that will not alter the bytes you are trying to send, like ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Oh thanks. My networking knowledge is practically non-existent and there is nearly no documentation. The answers worked well.